# How to send get http request with httpParams from angular to nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, parameters

I want to send a http request to get some filtered data from a Complaint model, from angular app to nodejs api.

angular :

```
  getFiletredComplaints() {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('status', this.chosenStatus)
      .set('type', this.chosenType)
    this.http.get("/api/complaints/filteredComplaints", { params }).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
```

---

node :

---

```
export default function (router) {
 router.get('/complaints/filteredComplaints', isAdmin, isLoggedIn, filterComplaints) // no doc writed
}
```

---

```
export async function filterComplaints(req, res) {

  console.log(req.query.params);

  try 
    var data = {
    sampleTime: '1450632410296',
    data: '76.36731:3.4651554:0.5665419'
}
    return res.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).end()
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read and test if my params sent successfully but I got this error :

> error "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ _id: 'filteredComplaints'
>   }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Complaint\""

Comment: I think that you are hitting wrong route in your application.

Comment: can explain how exactly